# Hashmap-storing and querying sql databases

Tags: mysql, database, hashmap

I want to encrypt data then upload to a mysql database and deploy to a cloud server. Can hashmap be used to perform queries on the encrypted data without decrypting it on the server?

Comment: Yes. It might be possible. Or maybe it's impossible. Who knows? Perhaps, if you shared more details of the problem you want to solve, you'd get some useful answers.

Comment: @Magnamag, made changes to the question. I welcome your input.

Comment: If I understand well, you want to keep the unencrypted data on a `HashMap` using the database's primary key, kind of a cache, but with the data unencrypted. Is this correct?

Comment: And, you'd need to query this `HashMap` to filter, order, grouping, etc, so you don't have to unencrypt what you have in the database, correct?

Comment: @ Magnamag. yes, but some of the data in the database too will be encrypted. so how do i implement hashmap to query this data? Is it as you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear enough, we dont have enough info to answer, but since i faced the same issue today. i will share my solution (I use JPA) , it could help.

there are 2 ways to do it:

1- use the HashMap as an attribute< i didnt try this.

2- u can create tables to satisfy your need.
for me i needed to store a word, and IDs of which titles they appeared at, 
thus i needed 2 tables, and Mapped them using 1-Many mapping.

u could also use another option and have a row for each duplicate value:
e.g:

1    "NameX"     "Hoppy1"

2    "NameX"     "Hoppy2"

3    "NameY"     "Hoppy1"